# Forcing listview to scroll down to a particular group. C#

Tags: c#, listview

I'm having a listview control on my windows form accomodating number of items under particular groups ,namely hardware, sanitary, tools, paint etc etc. Since the list of items can be too big to choose items from in reasonable time, so I have a menu strip above the listview control containing the names of the groups inside the listview control, what i want to do is to have a handler for a menu strip that scrolls down the listview to the particular group to save the time. 
how can it be done, i did google, but couldn't come up with a good way of doing it.

Comment: if the answer worked, please click the checkmark so this moves off the Unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is to get the first item in the desired `Group`, then use the `EnsureVisible` method on it.  This will do what it sounds like, make sure that item is visible.  If it is off-screen, it will scroll that item to the bottom of the viewable items:

```
// ToDo: check that the groups HAS items
ListViewitem lvi = myLV.Groups["myGroup"].Items[0];
lvi.EnsureVisible();
```

Another way -- which is probably what you want -- would be to try to make that same ListViewItem the `TopItem` which may scroll more of the Group into the viewable area:

```
myLV.TopItem = lvi;
```